# How to use AppScript to persist a google sheet as a table in BigQuery

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-bigquery

I'd like to save the content of a Google sheet in BigQuery as a table using App script.

So far we create a table "A" in BigQuery which is synced with the Google Sheet. And then we create an App script which queries the table A and saves it as table B. The script is quite similar to the one described in [Jun Kaneko's article *Integrate Google Spreadsheet with Big Query by Apps Script*](https://medium.com/@goodpic/integrate-google-spreadsheet-with-big-query-by-apps-script-d9c7574af64).

This solution works very well, but we have to create a new table A, every time we change the table structure in google Sheet. Therefore I was wondering how we could save the content of the google sheet directly as table B without a table A in BigQuery. The query should use the first row as column names and all following rows as content.

Comment: What's table A? What's table B? What's your actual code? Which part is not working? How do we reproduce your problem (please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))? Please try to make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: As far as I understood from the article you posted, it's doing the opposite. the spreadsheet is being updated  by the data in  BigQuery. Have you tried to reproduce the scenario ? Where did you stop and which issues are you facing ? Also please update your question with examples of the tables outputs and indicate the triggers you want to use to create the tables and so on. Br’s

Comment: Thanks for your questions. To make it more precise, let's put it this way: 

We have a google sheet with Column A - G and we want to have a script which persists the content of this google sheet as a table in BigQuery using the first rows as fieldnames and the rows below as content/data.

How would that work?

The tutorial linked above queries a query in big query and saves the result as a table in BigQuery. We do not want to query a query but save the content of a google sheet. 

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

**===== Edit**

As taking into consideration new information from the OP, it's not possible to be performed without creating a new table or deleting and recreating at every change. The table schema is not so flexible on BigQuery, you can't for example add a new column without recreate the table. Check more detail about [changing schemas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas).

=====

There is a easy way to perform what you want without having to program an [App Script](https://www.google.com/script/start/).

Just create an BigQuery table using the Google Spreadsheet as the information source. This is a native way for doing this.

##### Here is the procedure to do so:

- Create your google spreadsheet, define the columns (you can insert your data whatever you what):
  [image]
- Back to BigQuery, create your data set:
  [image]
- In the dataset, create the table defining the source data as `Drive` → `Google Sheet`. As the fist line of your `sheet` is your table header, configure in the `Advanced Options` → `Header rows to skip = 1`:

URI:

[image]

On Bq:
[image]

- Finally you will have your data on BigQuery, updated everytime you change the spreadsheet:
  [image]

[image]

Please inform if you have any doubt or problem.

Comment: Thanks @ewertonsvila, The way described is actually the way we do it today. Additionally we have an app script to persist the table out of Google sheet as there are access issues if you use a non-persisted table in a query which should be requested from Tableau. The disadvantage is, that you have to create the table new each time you change the format of the table in your Google sheet. That's why I was wondering if we could persist a google sheet directly into a BigQuery table.

Comment: Sorry, the details you provided didn't explain those details. Unfortunately you **can't do this**. The table schema is not so flexible on BigQuery, you can't for example add a new column without recreate the table. Check more detail about [changing schemas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/manually-changing-schemas).